# How to use HttpServletResponse when using Openfeign client

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, servlets, openfeign

I am trying to create and use a Openfeignclient to consume a spring boot REST API

Here is my API

```
@GetMapping("/report/pdf")
public void exportToPDF(@Param("portName") String portName,
        @Param("reportDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate reportDate,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=access_report_"+ portName + "_" + reportDate + ".pdf";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> accessDataMap = portDataService.generatePortAccessReport(portName, reportDate);

    PortAccessDataReportPDFExporter exporter = new PortAccessDataReportPDFExporter(accessDataMap);
    exporter.export(response, portName, reportDate);

}
```

Here is my FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(value = "port-access-data-client", url = "http://localhost:8081/port-data/")
public interface PortAccessDataClient {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "report/pdf")
public void exportToPDF(@RequestParam("portName") String portName,
                        @RequestParam("reportDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate reportDate,
                        HttpServletResponse response);
```

}

Here is a controller to test the FeignClient

```
@GetMapping("report/pdf")
public void generateReportForPortByDatePDF(@Param("portName") String portName,
                                           @Param("reportDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate reportDate,
                                           HttpServletResponse response){
    portAccessDataClient.exportToPDF(portName, reportDate, response);

}
```

When I call this test controller I am receiving this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I think the reason for this error is I have open an output stream of same HttpServletResponse twice.

Can anyone explain me the reason for above error, If I am wrong

I am expecting a method to tackle above scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't mean "open an output stream of same HttpServletResponse twice", it means "calling `getWriter()` and `getOutputstream()` for the same response without `reset()`" ... the solution details would be in your `export` method/the feign stubs.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a HttpServletResponse object in the feign client function?